# How to find the last targeted string in a string by Python?

Tags: python, string

We all know how to find the first targeted string in a string.

```
string.index('abc')
```

So this code will help me to find the first place that 'abc' appears in string.

However, I want to know how to find the last 'abc' location.

I already figured out an algorithm, but it is stupid.

```
1. reverse whole string and 'abc'.
2. temp_Location = string.index('cba')
3. exactly_Location = len(string) - temp_Location - len('cba')
```

I know it is really silly... Can somebody tell me how to do it smart?

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [str.rindex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

```
s = 'abcabc'
s.rindex('abc')  # evaluates to 3
```

Comment: Oh my god... I didn't know this convenient function before! Deeply thank you!

Comment: @MarsLee :) glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Python [regex library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), which will provide more functionality if needed.

In your case, you could simply do:

```
import re
s = 'abcabc'
[i.start() for i in re.finditer('abc', s)][-1] #last index from all match indices
```

Comment: This method is cool! I am also working hard on Regex. Thank you for giving me a new thinking! I will upvote you :)